# React - prop .isRequired

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm getting this warning

Failed prop type: The prop `queryObjState.isRequired` is marked as required in `RefineSearchBar`, but its value is `undefined`.

Why is the prop required, I haven't got isRequired in propTypes.

Any help would be great, Thanks!

```
export default function RefineSearchBar({ travelAdvisorApi, queryObjState }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    location: '',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
    },
    radius: 5,
    priceLevel: '',
  });
  console.log(queryObjState);
  const setLocationResponse = (location, coordinates, radius = 5) => {
    setFormData((prev) => ({
      ...prev, location, coordinates, radius,
    }));
  };
  const submitForm = () => {
    if (!formData.coordinates.latitude && !formData.coordinates.longitude) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch(setSearchQueries(formData));
    travelAdvisorApi(formData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="sidebar w-100 d-flex justify-content-evenly align-items-start py-2">
      <HandleAutocomplete
        setLocationResponse={setLocationResponse}
        queryLocation={queryObjState.location}
      />
      <Container fluid>
        <Button type="button" onClick={submitForm}>
          Refine Search
        </Button>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

RefineSearchBar.propTypes = {
  travelAdvisorApi: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  queryObjState: PropTypes.shape(PropTypes.any),
};
RefineSearchBar.defaultProps = {
  queryObjState: {
    location: '',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
    },
    radius: 5,
    priceLevel: '',
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to this issue in `prop-types`](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/155) the error shows up when you pass anything other than a javascript Object to `PropTypes.shape(...)`.

You can omit it using `PropTypes.any` directly

```js
RefineSearchBar.propTypes = {
  travelAdvisorApi: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  queryObjState: PropTypes.any,
};
```

But if you want to define the `prop` correctly then you have to give a valid javascript object to `PropTypes.shape` with each subattribute and its validation with `PropTypes`:

```js
RefineSearchBar.propTypes = {
  travelAdvisorApi: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  queryObjState: PropTypes.shape({
    location: PropTypes.string,
    coordinates: PropTypes.shape({
      latitude: PropTypes.number,
      longitude: PropTypes.number,
    }),
    radius: PropTypes.number,
    priceLevel: PropTypes.string,
  }),
};
```